# How do I override init?

Tags: python

I have:

```
Class A:
    def __init__(self, y):
        blah, blah, blah
    def af(self, h):
        print "this"
```

I over ride the defs like this:

```
def my_init(self,h):
    gangsta wangsta
def aff(self,h):
    print "that"

A.af = aff # works
A.__init__ = my_init # doesn't work
```

It doesn't work with init....How do I do it w/ `__init__`?

Comment: In what way did it not work?

Comment: gangsta wangsta is probably the problem ...

Comment: No error, A.__init__ ends up being "blah, blah, blah" rather than "gangsta wangsta"

Comment: @Joran...it's obviously just to simplify the problem...You seriously think we have an init function w/ gangsta wangsta??

Comment: not according to my example below ... that is actual python ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to subclass:

```
class B(A):
     __init__ = my_init
```

Comment: this is the *correct* answer although it doesnt address the method the op is asking about (+1 all the same for being the right answer)

Comment: Because it is considered impolite to change the behavior of a class globally.  After all, you didn't ask any of the other modules which might use class `A` what they thought about this change ...

Answer (score 2):

what exactly is the problem?

```
>>> class X:
...   def __init__(self):
...     print "Original Init!"
...
>>> def new_init(self):
...    print "OK New Init"
>>> X()
Original Init!
>>> X.__init__ = new_init
>>> X()
OK New Init
```

Comment: I was just going to comment about this.